# Default Object being modified because of LINQ Query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'm doing the following code to filter a list of objects before it gets sent off to be printed.

```
Dim printList As New List(Of dispillPatient)
For Each pat As dispillPatient In patList
    If (From meds In pat.Medication Select meds Where meds.Print = True).Count > 0 Then
        Dim patAdd As New dispillPatient
        patAdd = pat
        patAdd.Medication = DirectCast((From meds In pat.Medication Select meds Where meds.Print = True).ToList, List(Of dispillMedication))
        printList.Add(patAdd)
    End If
Next
```

What is happening is `patList`, which is my initial list, for every `dispillPatient` inside of it, that specific patients Medication object (which is another list), is being shorten to the list that is returned to the `patAdd` object.

I think this has something to do with both the way that .NET makes the copy of my `pat` object when I do `patAdd = pat` and the LINQ query that I'm using. Has anyone had a similar issue before and\or what can I do to keep my initial list from getting truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the object represented by `pat` is a `Class`, then the object does NOT get copied when you assign it to `patAdd`, only the reference to the object gets copied so you now have two references to the same object.

If you want to create a copy of the object, you'll need to write your own `Copy` method which does this manually, then write something like `patAdd = pat.Copy()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
patAdd = pat
```

This is your problem. This does *not* create a copy of your `pat` instance, this simply makes your `patAdd` variable point to the same instance as the `pat` variable.

In order to do this, you'll have to create a new `dispillPatient` object based upon `pat` and store *that* instance in `patAdd`.

While there's no particular idiom defined for doing this, some common ways are copy constructors:

```
Public Sub New(source as dispillPatient)
    ' copy whatever is necessary from source, realizing that any
    ' other reference types -- like lists -- also need to be duplicated
    ' in similar fashion
End Sub
```

Or a Copy/Clone function

```
Public Function Clone() As dispillPatient
    Dim output as new dispillPatient

    ' copy whatever is necessary to output, realizing that any
    ' other reference types -- like lists -- also need to be duplicated
    ' in similar fashion

    return output
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference assignment - no copy is made!

```
patAdd = pat
```

That means that patAdd and pat are one and the same thing!

This modifies patAdd (and since pat is the same thing, it too is modified)

```
patAdd.Medication = DirectCast((From meds In pat.Medication Select meds Where meds.Print = True).ToList, List(Of dispillMedication))
```